# Spring WebFlux WebFilter: Response body modification has no effect

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I want to modify every response generated by my Spring Boot application. For that I have created a WebFilter component that looks like this:

```java
@Component
public class EncryptionFilter implements WebFilter {
  @Override
  public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
    Decorator decorator = new Decorator(exchange.getResponse());
    return chain.filter(exchange.mutate().response(decorator).build());
  }

  public class Decorator extends ServerHttpResponseDecorator {
    public Decorator(ServerHttpResponse delegate) {
      super(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
      Mono<DataBuffer> modifiedBody = Mono.from(body)
          .map(dataBuffer -> {
            byte[] content = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
            dataBuffer.read(content);
            String originalContent = new String(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            String modifiedContent = originalContent + " Modified";
            return getDelegate().bufferFactory().wrap(modifiedContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
          });

      return super.writeWith(modifiedBody);
    }
  }
}
```

I can see that my filter is getting called and that I can read the original response. However, the client still receives the original response body. My assumption is that somewhere the response is already written to the client, before I am actually modifying it.

Using the `@Order` annotation doesn't seem to have an effect, I've tried both the lowest and highest precedence. I have also tried disabling all other filters, so this filter is the only one being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to rewrite the `Content-Length` header, like this:

```java
@Override
public Mono<Void> writeWith(Publisher<? extends DataBuffer> body) {
    Mono<DataBuffer> modifiedBody = Mono.from(body)
        .map(dataBuffer -> {
            byte[] content = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
            dataBuffer.read(content);
            String originalContent = new String(content, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            String modifiedContent = originalContent + " Modified";

            byte[] modifiedContentBytes = modifiedContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            getHeaders().setContentLength(modifiedContentBytes.length);

            return getDelegate().bufferFactory().wrap(modifiedContentBytes);
        });

    return super.writeWith(modifiedBody);
}
```

This resolves the issue, tested with the following endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public Mono<String> test(){
    return Mono.just("Test");
}
```

Response:

> Test Modified

Comment: Although certainly correct, it unfortunately did not resolve the issue :\

Comment: @Ahatius please provide more info about your case. I've updated my answer with my endpoint.

Comment: I copied the relevant classes from the main application to the test application to eliminate any effects from other dependencies. While copying, I left in a @ConditionalOnProperty annotation, that of course did not work, because the test project did not have the appropriate config. After removing the annotation and adding the content length, it indeed worked :) Thank you